# How can I port this c# code to f# for handling SFML events

Tags: c#, f#, sfml

I am trying to create a SFML app in F# and as there are no f# tutorials for the same, I am trying to learn from the c# ones. I don't know c# at all and only the basics of f#.

I came across this piece of code in C# and I am not sure what would the equivalent F# code be.

```
   static void Main()
        {
            ...

            window.KeyPressed += new EventHandler<KeyEventArgs>(OnKeyPressed);

            ...

        }

        static void OnKeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = (Window)sender;
            if (e.Code == Keyboard.Key.Escape)
                window.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F# converts events into an `IEvent<TDelegate, TArgs>` which exposes an `AddHandler` method, as well as the `IObservable.Subscribe` method.

You can use `AddHandler` to add a delegate, the equivalent of `+=` in C#.

```
window.KeyPress.AddHandler(fun sender evt -> printfn "Pressed %A" evt.Code)
```

If you want to do event processing, it's probably better to treat the event as an observable.

```
window.KeyPress |> Observable.op... |> Observable.subscribe(fun evt -> printfn "Pressed %A" evt.Code)
```

There's also an `Event` module that lets you compose events. Your current example could be rewritten as:

```
window.KeyPress 
|> Event.filter(fun evt -> evt.Code = Keyboard.Key.Escape) 
|> Event.add (fun _ -> window.Close())
```

Comment: Are there any major pros/cons for any of the 3 approaches? Or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: If you want to simplify removing the handler, prefer subscribe, because it gives you a disposable to remove the handler. `Event.add` is better for type inference. Otherwise personal preference.